# Where can i get the appId that pass to submitTask function in javascript SDK of Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

i am using this line of code:

`microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(customerInfo, "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");`

from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-tabs#example-submitting-the-result-of-a-task-module).

The second parameter is of GUID(appId). where can i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the application id in the menifest.json file, the property name is "id"(root level property), placeholder is %MICROSOFT-APP-ID% here.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "%MICROSOFT-APP-ID%",
  "packageName": "com.example.myapp",
  "devicePermissions" : [ "geolocation", "media" ],
  "developer": {
    "name": "Publisher Name",
    "websiteUrl": "https://website.com/",
    "privacyUrl": "https://website.com/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://website.com/app-tos",
    "mpnId": "1234567890"
  },
...
```

**Update:**
As Wajeed mentioned. If the id in menifest.json is not same as your bot id, use bot id instead.

Comment: In most of the cases your Bot Id and Id of manifest is same. If not, please pass the Bot Id to microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask().

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT yes, i updated my anwser for this case.

Answer (score 0):

CompletionBotId or app ID specifies a bot App ID to send the result of the user's interaction with the task module. If specified, the bot will receive a task/submit invoke event with a JSON object in the event payload.
Please take a look at [taskInfo Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview#the-taskinfo-object) for more information.